# Why doesn't Gradle include transitive dependencies in compile / runtime classpath?

Tags: build, build-system, dependency-management

I'm learning how Gradle works, and I can't understand how it resolves a project transitive dependencies.

For now, I have two projects :

- projectA : which has a couple of dependencies on external libraries
- projectB : which has only one dependency on projectA

No matter how I try, when I build projectB, gradle doesn't include any projectA dependencies (X and Y) in projectB's compile or runtime classpath. I've only managed to make it work by including projectA's dependencies in projectB's build script, which, in my opinion does not make any sense. These dependencies should be automatically attached to projectB. I'm pretty sure I'm missing something but I can't figure out what.

I've read about "lib dependencies", but it seems to apply only to local projects like described [here](http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/multi_project_builds.html#sec:project_jar_dependencies), not on external dependencies.

Here is the build.gradle I use in the root project (the one that contains both projectA and projectB) :

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.3'
    }
}

subprojects {
    apply plugin: 'java'
    apply plugin: 'idea'

    group = 'com.company'

    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        add(new org.apache.ivy.plugins.resolver.SshResolver()) {
            name = 'customRepo'
            addIvyPattern "ssh://.../repository/[organization]/[module]/[revision]/[module].xml"
            addArtifactPattern "ssh://.../[organization]/[module]/[revision]/[module](-[classifier]).[ext]"
        }
    }

    sourceSets {
        main {
            java {
                srcDir 'src/'
            }
        }
    }

    idea.module { downloadSources = true }

    // task that create sources jar
    task sourceJar(type: Jar) {
        from sourceSets.main.java
        classifier 'sources'
    }

    // Publishing configuration
    uploadArchives {
        repositories {
            add project.repositories.customRepo
        }
    }

    artifacts {
        archives(sourceJar) {
            name "$name-sources"
            type 'source'
            builtBy sourceJar
        }
    }
}
```

This one concerns projectA only :

```
version = '1.0'
dependencies {
    compile 'com.company:X:1.0'
    compile 'com.company:B:1.0'
}
```

And this is the one used by projectB :

```
version = '1.0'
dependencies {
    compile ('com.company:projectA:1.0') {
        transitive = true
    }
}
```

Thank you in advance for any help, and please, apologize me for my bad English.

Comment: 2 things: transitive is on by default AND dependency on another project in the same multi-module project should be specified like this: `compile project(":projectA")`

Comment: I have a similar question, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29661824/android-aar-dependencies#. So far I could not get it to work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Finally, the problem didn't come from the scripts. I've just cleared gradle's cache, and each project's build folder, to make this work.

Comment: Seriously spent the last 6 hours trying to get this to work and it was the caches. Should've checked there first. Thanks!

Answer (score 23):

*I know that this specific version of the question has already been solved, but my searching brought me here and I hope I can save some people the hassle of figuring this out.*

### Bad `foo/build.gradle`

```
dependencies {
    implementation 'com.example:widget:1.0.0'
}
```

### Good `foo/build.gradle`

```
dependencies {
    api 'com.example:widget:1.0.0'
}
```

### `bar/build.gradle`

```
dependencies {
    implementation project(path: ':foo')
}
```

---

`implementation` hides the widget dependency.

`api` makes the widget dependency transitive.

---

From https://stackoverflow.com/a/44493379/68086:

> From the [Gradle documentation](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/java_library_plugin.html#sec:java_library_separation):
>
> > ```
> > dependencies {
> >     api 'commons-httpclient:commons-httpclient:3.1'
> >     implementation 'org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:3.5'
> > }
> > ```
> >
> > Dependencies appearing in the `api` configurations will be
> >     transitively exposed to consumers of the library, and as such will
> >     appear on the compile classpath of consumers.
> >
> > Dependencies found in the `implementation` configuration will, on the
> >     other hand, not be exposed to consumers, and therefore not leak into
> >     the consumers' compile classpath. This comes with several benefits:
> >
> > - dependencies do not leak into the compile classpath of consumers anymore, so you will never accidentally depend on a transitive
> >       dependency
> > - faster compilation thanks to reduced classpath size
> > - less recompilations when implementation dependencies change: consumers would not need to be recompiled
> > - cleaner publishing: when used in conjunction with the new maven-publish plugin, Java libraries produce POM files that
> >       distinguish exactly between what is required to compile against the
> >       library and what is required to use the library at runtime (in other
> >       words, don't mix what is needed to compile the library itself and what
> >       is needed to compile against the library).
> >
> > **The compile configuration still exists, but should not be used as it will not offer the guarantees that the `api` and `implementation`
> >     configurations provide.**

Comment: I have the same issue, and I'm using dependency just like yours, but `api` does not expose its dependency to dependent project, which I'm using with `implementation` configuration in dependent project. Whereas `compile` works as expected when used in dependent project

Comment: got it, I had the dependency with configuration defined in dependencies, once removed, it was successful

Comment: This still doesn't work for compileOnlyApi

Answer (score 1):

Put the following line in projectB's dependencies.

compile project(':projectA')