# Library dependency class use in app android

Tags: android, kotlin, android-gradle-plugin, gradle-dependencies, google-ads-api

I am developing library and using that library as aar to my app as below sample project.

### Library Project:

```
public class UserDevice {
    private static final String TAG = "UserDevice";
    private static Context mContext;

    public UserDevice(final Context context) {
        mContext = context.getApplicationContext();
    }

    private static String getAdvertisementId(Context context) {
        String _myads = null;
        try {
            String id = com.google.android.gms.ads.identifier.AdvertisingIdClient.getAdvertisingIdInfo(context).getId();
            if (id != null) {
                _myads = id;
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Could not get det ID.", e);
        }
        return _myads;
    }
}
//build.gradle
android {
    compileSdkVersion 29
    buildToolsVersion "29.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 29
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        consumerProguardFiles 'consumer-rules.pro'
    }
...
}

dependencies {
    // default dependencies 
    // ...

    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:17.2.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:19.0.1'
}
```

### App Project:

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        val device = UserDevice(this) //

        btn_show_ads.setOnClickListener {
            label_ads_id.text = device.myads
            Log.d("App", "Device Ads id is: ${device.myads}")
        }
    }
}
/// build.gradle
dependencies {
    // default dependencies 
    // ...
    compile(name: 'adslibrary', ext: 'aar')
    // compile project(path: ':adslibrary')
}
```

But what happened here is that it giving error

```
2020-05-11 10:11:32.489 21925-21991/com.bhavdip.myadstest E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-2
    Process: com.bhavdip.myadstest, PID: 21925
    java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lcom/google/android/gms/ads/identifier/AdvertisingIdClient;
        at com.bhavdip.adslibrary.CRDevice.getAdvertisementId(Unknown Source:2)
        at com.bhavdip.adslibrary.CRDevice$1.run(Unknown Source:4)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
     Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.google.android.gms.ads.identifier.AdvertisingIdClient" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.bhavdip.myadstest-fP-f0WbH8_ErVLG3QBcgkQ==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.bhavdip.myadstest-fP-f0WbH8_ErVLG3QBcgkQ==/lib/arm, /system/lib, /vendor/lib]]
        at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:134)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:379)
```

I already added and am using `gms:play-services-ads` dependency in library. The app again asks me to add those dependency forcefully.

**If I will add the dependency to the app it works fine**, but I don't want to add that dependency again. **I don't want to expose my library dependency to end user or developer**. Adds below dependency to my-library.

```
//For advertisement ID
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:19.1.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:17.2.1'
```

**Reference links**: I tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44493378/whats-the-difference-between-implementation-and-compile-in-gradle/44493379#48388463) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17416629/why-doesnt-gradle-include-transitive-dependencies-in-compile-runtime-classpat) too. I also checked all answers in reference links.

I have tried `multidex`, `transitive` and also changed `implementation` to `api` or `compile`. in app project like this.

```
// Use transitive
compile(name: 'adslibrary', ext: 'aar') {
    transitive = true
}
```

----- EDIT for **Questions** -----

- What is `transitive`? How it works?
- How `multidex` works in library?

I might miss something to change. Please help me out of this problem.

Comment: downgrade `com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:19.0.1`

Comment: I have tried but not worked after downgrade `gms:play-services-ads` to 19.0.1.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use `api` instead of implementation

```
api 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:19.1.0'
api 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:17.2.1'
```

[implementation vs api](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46999766/5134215)

`api` - dependency will be exposed to the module which uses this library

`implementation` - dependency will be resolved only in this module

`transitive=false` is to skip the `api` dependencies of the library modules

Comment: @AndyBoy that question is deleted it seems, can you explain your issue you are facing when using the `api` in the library module

Comment: Are you having the library as another module in the app project?

Comment: `compile project(':my-library')` in app and in library using above dependency. No another module only added aar file from `libs`

Comment: There are two ways to add library as a dependency to your app as mentioned in this https://stackoverflow.com/a/49445004/5134215
Try the first way & check whether you did it properly.

Comment: I have added that properly both the way it is working fine if I add given dependency again in app.

Comment: Please see issue again as I have edited with more details with code

Comment: Hey, I told you to use `api` instead of `implementation` in your library `build.gradle`, Still you are having `implementation`? Kindly read my solution properly & the link I have gave above

Comment: Yes,  I had tried with `api` also but still was crashing while using it. You can try with given project.

Comment: You must use `api` in library if you want to expose the dependency to app, try to fix the crash you are getting on using `api`, post the crash log here

Comment: I have added error log in issue description. please have a look into.

Comment: You are getting the error why using `api` in the library right?
Did you have Application class in your app?
Try disabling the instant run & check did you configured the multidex properly
https://stackoverflow.com/q/43435658/5134215
https://stackoverflow.com/q/22399572/5134215